# FTP not working with WiFi or Tethering

Tags: wireless-networking, ftp, tethering

My laptop has suddenly starting having issues when I FTP files to my website. I can send emails and browse web pages with no problem but FTP access is intermittent. If I plug a network cable in there are no problems.

I have tried changing my wifi channel but it was no help. I tried connecting to the internet by tethering my phone, but that has exactly the same problem. I also tried another FTP client and had the same issue.

I'm using Windows 7 and installed service pack 1 just a few days ago.

What could be causing FTP (and only FTP) to stop working when tethering or connecting by Wi-Fi but not causing a problem with a wired connection.

Comment: After a couple of days it fixed itself. I don't know why.